# CONVERT fails but TRY_CONVERT successfully convert same data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column with dates stored as strings (`NVARCHAR(500)`), in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

This query gets all rows with a non null value in my date_column, 13955 rows returned, 18359 total rows on table.

```sql
SELECT ID, date_column
FROM [MyTable] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    client = 178425
    AND folder = 1422720
    AND date_column IS NOT NULL
```

Filtering for rows that successfully converted the string to a date value using TRY_CONVERT. Returned all 13955 rows, indicating all of them are valid dates.

```sql
SELECT ID, date_column
FROM [MyTable] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    client = 178425
    AND folder = 1422720
    AND date_column IS NOT NULL
    AND TRY_CONVERT(DATE, date_column, 103) IS NOT NULL
```

Now converting the column to a date in the select statement, again no errors and all 13955 rows returned.

```sql
SELECT ID, CONVERT(DATE, date_column, 103)
FROM [MyTable] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    client = 178425
    AND folder = 1422720
    AND date_column IS NOT NULL
    AND TRY_CONVERT(DATE, date_column, 103) IS NOT NULL
```

So I assumed all NON-NULL values are valid dates, right?

But then if I remove the TRY_CONVERT from the where statement, I receive an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```sql
SELECT ID, CONVERT(DATE, date_column, 103)
FROM [MyTable] WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE
    client = 178425
    AND folder = 1422720
    AND date_column IS NOT NULL
```

How can this be? ALL Non NULL rows are valid dates but only if I use `TRY_CONVERT` function there?
Any ideas on how to find the faulty values in my table?

PS. Not providing sample data because all tests I did out of this specific table worked as expected. I have no Idea what is causing this problem...

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Does `select Id, Date_Column from MyTable where Date_Column is not NULL and Try_Convert( Date, Date_Column, 103 ) is NULL;` return anything interesting?

Comment: Not my downvote but I imagine it will turn out the description is incorrect and in reality the WHERE clause includes an additional predicate that filters out some rows with invalid values. Then it will be execution plan dependent whether the CONVERT runs before the filter or vice versa

Comment: @HABO It returns nothing. I forgot to include this in the description.

Comment: @MartinSmith In fact there is another predicate, two INT values that I use to filter the table, and are used in all the queries above. I assumed as all used the same filters and the convert is on the SELECT part, not in the WHERE, I could remove them from the examples, sorry. Can you provide some help on how to identify an execution plan problem?

--- EDIT: including this other filters in the example above.

Comment: @Tchaki we can't guess what's stored in the table. Storing dates as strings is a huge bug to begin with (and a waste of space). Neither CONVERT or TRY_CONVERT are broken. Store the IDs from each query to temporary tables and check the difference. What do those missing rows contains?

Comment: @Tchaki `Not providing sample data` then the question will be closed. You're asking people to guess. It's quite possible the *tests* are wrong. `NOLOCK` means your query will see data that may be rolled back in the next millisecond for example. If you use NOLOCK there's no guarantee you're querying the same data every time. SQL Server 2012 is 10 years old and went out of support 6 years ago. It may have had some weird bug but I doubt it.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis the question isn't good. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence and this question doesn't have any. It's missing the table schema, sample data, actual and desired output. It's impossible to test it. It wouldn't be the first time someone was querying the wrong database, or looking at the wrong data. Using NOLOCK means the query will read uncommitted rows that may be rolled back or replaced. The question contains enough smells as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially `Martin Smith`'s comment. I believe it deserves to be an answer. Because it *is* the answer.

`convert` can fail even in rows that your `select` never returns due to `where`.

In contrast, `try_convert` never fails, and because your `where` eliminates problematic rows, you are left wondering what the title says.

For OP's post, it means that some client/folder combination other than `178425/1422720` has a [date_column] which cannot be converted.